# Why can't I add points to a Group in PaperJS?

Tags: paperjs

```
grid = new Group();
for (y = 0; y < isoSteps; y++) {
    for (x = 0; x < isoSteps; x++) {
        p = new Point(x * stepSize, y * stepSize);
        grid.addChild(p);
    }
}
```

The code above gives me a " TypeError: item._remove is not a function" error.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a point to a path and that path to a group.  Groups are made up of paperjs items.  `Point` is not an item, just a basic type.

Paperjs items contain a remove function and point does not. Thats probably why youre getting that TypeError.